# Google App Script getting form response by time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get form responses submitted in the last 1 hour to limit the number of responses that I'll later use to process the latest response. But I keep getting an error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getId" of undefined. at onSubmit(form:67)"
Below is my code snippet. Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

```
function onSubmit() {

  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(d.getHours() - 1);
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
//  var form_responses = form.getResponses();
  var form_responses = form.getResponses(d);
  var respID_Idx = form_responses.length-1;
  var last_form_res_id = form_responses[respID_Idx].getId();

  var las_resp = form.getResponse(last_form_res_id);

  var item_res = las_resp.getItemResponses();
```

Comment: Probably, There're no form responses in the last hour.

Comment: @sandy I think you meant `< 0`

Comment: Yes, it needs to be `if (respID_Idx < 0) {return;}`